# Populate default values during record creation - LWC quick action vs defaultFieldValues button/link

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction

In terms of prepopulating values on a record creation modal, I'm wondering what advantage, if any, the LWC quick action technique has over the much easier button/link technique.

LWC quick action technique:
https://blog.salesforcecasts.com/navigate-to-a-new-record-with-default-values-in-lwc/

Button/link technique:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWCs will let you do more than just a button, such as querying additional information that isn't available on the record or taking user input but if all you need is to launch the new record page with default values set which you have easy access to, the button/link should be easier.